# jquery encode array for GET queryString

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have an array of id's in JS, like so

```
var ids = [123,456,789]
```

I am trying to pass them as part of a querystring in a GET request to a .NET API application. From what I understand .NET needs the querystring to resemble `endpoint/ids=123&ids=345&ids=789` or similar.

I've tried using `$.param({ ids: ids } )` but it ends up as `ids%5B%5D=123&ids%5B%5D=456&ids%5B%5D=789`

How can I do this?

Here's my html link to use it. I'm using `knockout databinding` and `observables`

```html
<a class="btn btn-sm btn-default" data-bind="attr:{'href':'bill/' + bills().map((data) => {return data.billId;}), 'target':'_blank'}">
  <i class="fa fa-print"></i> 
  Click
</a>
```

and it currently returns
`bill/123,456,789`

Comment: While would query string have duplicate keys?

Comment: It would help a lot to see your full JS and HTML here. It looks like you need to use `traditional: true` on the AJAX call

Comment: @guest271314 that's how the MVC/WebAPI the ModelBinder does it. PHP generally uses `foo[]=1,2,3`, MVC does `foo=1&foo=2&foo=3`

Comment: It's not .NET that "needs" anything. What you posted is simply an encoded URL query string. Did you encounter a problem?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan most certainly not. That what *Javascript* generates. Both PHP and MVC run on the *server*. And you *can't* pass `foo[]=1,2,3` in a URL

Comment: added the html that shows the href being generated

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm not sure the point you're making, especially with your painfully obvious 'PHP and MVC run on the server' comment, but it seems you've misunderstood what I'm saying. Here's a clearer explanation than I can make in a comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/701182/A-Custom-Model-Binder-for-Passing-Complex-Objects. See the first few paragraphs re. binding querystring fields to complex objects.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
ids.map(ids=> `ids=${id}`).join('&')
```

to create a string with ids=123&ids=345&ids=789. 
Aftwards you can just add the concattedIds to you url.

Would be something like this:

```html
<a class="btn btn-sm btn-default" data-bind="attr:{'href':'bill/' + bills().map((data) => `ids=${data.billId}`).join('&'), 'target':'_blank'}">
  <i class="fa fa-print"></i> 
  Click
</a>
```